# Acumos AI clio : Can not create pipeline

Tags: artificial-intelligence, pipeline, acumos

I have installed acumos clio release.
I am able to onboard sample model, create acu-compose but failing to create pipelines.

I understand there are few ways to create pipeline.

1. Design studio --> Workbench --> Pipeline --> create pipeline

Has no url text box and when created it throws "Server error", logs suggests , "Malformed URL"

[PFA]
[image]

2. via Home --> Design Studio --> ML Workbench–>Projects --> --> create data pipeline ,
   It has URL box, but not sure, what value of URL to input ?

References few Jira : https://jira.acumos.org/browse/ACUMOS-4018

Comment: Hi Sandejai, I will recommend you to have a look on https://wiki.acumos.org/ 
I found this page in which there is a video related to MLWB pipeline :

https://wiki.acumos.org/display/REL/Boreas+Demos 

I found this also 

https://wiki.acumos.org/display/REL/Clio+Demos?preview=/20546727/26640880/Workbench%20ACUMOS-3251-3465%20-%201001.mp4

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to have a look on https://wiki.acumos.org/
I found this page in which there is a video related to MLWB pipeline :

https://wiki.acumos.org/display/REL/Boreas+Demos

I found this also

https://wiki.acumos.org/display/REL/Clio+Demos?preview=/20546727/26640880/Workbench%20ACUMOS-3251-3465%20-%201001.mp4

Perhaps it exists other demo or videos

Comment: issue persists, I thought the url will be auto generated/assigned during pipeline creation